# How does one continue code from the line where the function was on in Python?

Tags: python, function, class, variables

I have a `nameType()` function in my text game, and it is used two times:

1. Creating a stats class (or whatever) so the program can save them, and
2. A function in-game for some variable changing.

Here's the current code that this post targets (may be subject to change):

```
def TitleScreen():
blankHuge()
anar()
print('The Game of Hierarchy and Anarchy\nBy Roach\nText Edition\n▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬\nType "new" to start a new game.\nTo load a game, type "load".\nTo exit, type "exit".')
StartGame = input()
if StartGame == 'new':
    print('► Crew Member: Hello, fine man. I can see you are on an adventure to the land of Salbury.\nBefore you disembark the boat, please enter your name.')
    for filename in file:
        os.unlink(filename)
    nameType()
    global PlayerIG                   
    PlayerIG = Player(CharName)
    print('► Crew Member: Thanks for travelling with us, and have a great time,',PlayerIG.name,'.')
    saveGame()
    MainMenu()
# more stuff that aren't related down here...
```

Here's the `nameType()` function:

```
def nameType():
print('▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬')
CharName = input()
if CharName != '':
    if len(CharName) > 20:
        print('► The name is too long!')
        nameType()
    else:
        print('► Are you sure this is what you want as a name?\nIf so, type "yes".\nOtherwise, type "no".')
        confirmName = input()

        if confirmName == 'yes': # If this is true, then jump to next codeline from where the nameType() func was placed...
            pause() # Doesn't work

        if confirmName == 'no':
            nameType()
        else:
            print('► Invalid Input!')
            nameType()
```

And here's the function which is supposed to continue the code from where it was, but it doesn't work:

```
def pause():
pause = input('► Press Enter to continue.')
if pause != '':
    pause()
```

Is there any way I can continue my code?

Example (most likely not going to work):

```
def TitleScreen():
    ...
    nameType() # Someway, jump to next line after code in nameType() has been executed...
    global PlayerIG
    PlayerIG = Player(CharName) 
    ...
    saveGame()
    MainMenu() 

def management():
    ...
    opt = input()
    if opt = 'name':
        nameType() # Someway, jump to next line after code in nameType() has been executed...
        PlayerIG.nameWait = 12
        PlayerIG.heat = 0
    ...
```

**NOTE:** I have an idea of how this will work, but I'm not sure if it will work. It is:

```
# outside of nameType()
if confirmName == 'yes':
    ...
```

Comment: You'll need to store game state somewhere. You'll read that state from that store and start the game with that state.

Comment: Can you clear out what you want/need to do, please?

Comment: @erip I have stored the game state. Also, that was not my question. What I need to do is find a way to jump to the next line of code from where the `nameType()` function was placed.

Comment: I didn't answer your question because you're trying to solve an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). If you have game state, you can pass that into appropriate classes that will handle picking up the last checkpoint in the game.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My idea worked, using `if` outside the `nameType()` function *does* work. I used `global` (I know it's bad coding, but whatever), and now the function works.

```
def nameType():
global confirmName
global CharName
print('▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬')
CharName = input()
if CharName != '':
    if len(CharName) > 20:
        print('► The name is too long!')
        nameType()
    else:
        print('► Are you sure this is what you want as a name?\nIf so, type "yes".\nOtherwise, type "no".')
        confirmName = input()
# Items down here for the confirmName input removed

# This is the system for the 'jump':
if confirmName == 'blah1':
    # add stuff here...    
    if confirmName == 'no':
        # add stuff here...
    else:
        # add stuff here...
```